# Arduno as bridge between two i2c masters

Tags: i2c, raspberrypi

so I am gonna just jump right into the topic. Recently, I have been trying to build a project where I need to connect an ev3 to a raspberry pi. I have decided doing it by i2c after reading (and successfully replicating) an article about connecting an ev3 to arduino by i2c https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/connecting-ev3-arduino/.  However, after setting it up with raspberry pi, I realized a huge problem that I am facing, both of these devices acted as masters and I could not get them to connect to each other. So I decided to use an arduino between those two which transports the data that it receives to the other device, which I couldn't get working. I have no idea how to get it working anyways, it was just a hopeless try. Now I am doubting myself If I can't do it. So my question is, is such a project possible or should I just give up. If I should, what type of communication do you suggest that I use.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You successfully connected an Arduino to a device using I2C?  Then you added a Raspberry Pi putting 3 I2C devices on the same I2C bus and it does not work?  And instead of posting this to raspberrypi.stackexchange.com you are posting it here in arduino.stackexchange.com?  FYI, it is hard to imagine an I2C bus with more than one master.

Comment: An Arduino can be put into I2C slave mode, so I imagine a Raspberry Pi can be as well. I suggest asking on the Arduino Pi Stack Exchange how to do it. I can migrate this question there if you like.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5584/i2c-raspberri-pi-as-a-slave